# Learning Exploit Techniques using old Linux OS

Tags: linux, opcode, shellcode

I am learning how to write exploits. SInce in the new linux versions, they have a lot of stack protection mechanism. I have installed Linux "Hardy Heron". The reason why I choose Hardy Heron was because of the release day (2008 I guess)...and since the shellcoders handbook is from that time, I thought that the code examples must function, too.

[On my host system, I have Linux "Precise Penguin". So, when I wrote my exploits on the host system, I need to type the flag options: **-fno-stack-protector** or **-z execstack**.]

So I installed Linux "Hardy Heron" on VirtualBox. Then I try to write the typical "/bin/sh"-exploit, as in the book explained.

The code looks like the following:

```
Section .text

     global _start

_start:
       jmp  short GoToCall

execve: 
       pop esi
       xor eax, eax
       mov [esi+7], al
       lea ebx, [esi]
       mov [esi+8], ebx
       mov [esi+12], eax
       lea ecx, [esi+8]
       mov edx, [esi+12]
       mov ebx, esi
       mov al, 0xb
       int 0x80



GoToCall:
       call execve
       db '/bin/shJAAAAKKKK'
```

I extract the the opcodes using **objdump** and put it into a char array. 
But when I compile the shellcode code, e.g. execve_shellcode.c, with the command **gcc -o execve_shellcode execve_shellcode.c** and type **./execve_shellcode**
the nothing happens. I only get a new line. So, it looks the following:

```
user@linux:~/Desktop/Code$ ./execve_shellcode
user@linux:~/Desktop/Code$
```

Can somebody tell what is going wrong? Is there another protection mechanism on hardy heron? Btw, I also compiled it with the flag commands mentioned above, but with same result.

[Note: Since Hardy Heron is not supported anymore, I update & upgrade system by changing the file sources.list in /etc/apt. In that file, I replace the http://.... .ubuntu/ link with http://old-releases.ubuntu.com./ubuntu.]

I hope somebody can help me. I do not know why it is not working. Maybe the shellcode is wrong, but I cannot find any mistake or Hardy uses a protection mechanism which I do not know.

Can somebody help?

best regards,

Comment: You might want to ask on [security.se]

Comment: Oh, I did not know that site. Thx

Comment: Spawning a shell from shell usually looks like that, most likely you can type exit and return to the initial shell

Comment: no, it must lead to "$"-sign, or ?